# How to display the easy digital download $atts inside a custom shortcode?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a custom easy digital downloads (EDD) shortcode and I can't make the atts working. Meaning I would like to be able to change the category and tag names while using the shortcode, e.g :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[my_shortcode taxonomy="download_tag" field="name" terms="Premium"]' ); ?>
```

But all I get is the default term ( Free ).

The code:

```
    function my_shortcode_function($product_args, $content = null) {
    global $post;

            $current_page = get_query_var('paged');

            $offset = $current_page > 0 ? $per_page * ($current_page-1) : 0;
            $product_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'download',
                'posts_per_page' => '6',
                'tax_query' => array(                   
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'download_tag',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => 'Free'
                    ),
                ),
                'offset' => $offset
            );
            $products = new WP_Query($product_args);            

            if ($products->have_posts()) : $i = 1;
                while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post(); 

                $tags = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'download_tag' );// get tags link
                $tags = strip_tags( $tags ); // get rid of the tag link
                $category = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'download_category' ); // get category link

                echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">';
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-download-card-post' );   
                echo '</div>';

                     $i+=1;
             endwhile;              

            else :      
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );  
            endif; 
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function' );
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do it but I'm still new in php and the EDD docs lacks of useful examples for newbies like me. So I'll appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's funny that I implemented this from a woocommerce answer and it works like a charm. Now I can change the tag, category, or the number of posts. If anyone needs it here it is:

```
// Creating a shortcode that displays a random product image/thumbail
if( !function_exists('prod_listing_params') ) {
    function prod_listing_params( $atts ) {
         ob_start();

          $atts = shortcode_atts( array (
              'type' => 'download',
              'order' => 'date',
              'orderby' => 'title',
              'posts' => 6,
              'category' => '', // category name
              'tag' => '', // tag name
         ), $atts, 'list_products' );

         $query = new WP_Query( array(
              'post_type' => $atts['type'],
              'order' => $atts['order'],
              'orderby' => $atts['orderby'],
              'posts_per_page' => $atts['posts'],
              'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR', 
                  array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'download_category',
                     'field' => 'name',
                     'terms' => $atts['category'],
                  ),
                  array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'download_tag',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'terms' => $atts['tag'],
                 )  
            ),
        ) );

         if ( $query->have_posts() ) { $i = 1;
              ?>

                         <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
                         $tags = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'download_tag' );// get tags link
                        $tags = strip_tags( $tags ); // get rid of the tag link
                        $category = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'download_category' ); // get category link
                        ?>


                        <?php echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">';
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-download-card-post' );   
                        echo '</div>'; $i+=1; ?>

                         <?php endwhile;
                         wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

              <?php
              $myvar = ob_get_clean();
              return $myvar;
         }
    }
    add_shortcode( 'list_products', 'prod_listing_params' );
```

And the use:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[list_products tag="Free" posts="3"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: your code solved my problem. thank you so much